# Chrome not supporting for "Enter" key onkey press event

Tags: javascript

in chrome browser i am getting TypeError: translate is not a function:
The code is working in firefox correctly. but not in Chrome

Below is my code snippet:

Thanks in advance

```
<script language="javascript">
function translate(event)
{
  if ( event.keyCode == 13) 
  {
    submitForm('', 'mainForm');
  }
}
</script>

<form name="mainForm">
 <input id = "password"  maxlength="50" type = "password" 
                                                                   name = "password" width = "250px" onkeypress="javascript: translate(event)" />
</form>

 <script language="JavaScript">
    buttonGen("<%=mm.getMessage("IBE","IBE_PRMT_SIGN_IN_G" )%>", "javascript:submitForm('', 'mainForm')");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('password').keydown( function(e) {
    var key = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : 0;
    if(key == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        submitForm('', 'mainForm');
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PTauw/239/)**

or you can use `event.which` along with `event.keyCode`

```
function translate(event)
{
  if ( event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) 
  {
    submitForm('', 'mainForm');
  }
}
```

Comment: i have tried this code also, it not worked. and it showing translate is not a function

Comment: @ManjunathRJ:- Did you try to use the Jquery option for which I have added the jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Hi Rahul. In my project i am using plain javascript, no JQuery

Answer (score 0):

First rename the function, you create a global function that is look like is reserved by the browser and the second when you use onkeypress attribute you don't receive a event as parameter but you can use global event variable so your function has to look like

```
function myTranslate(){
    if ( event.keyCode == 13){
        submitForm('', 'mainForm');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rumen can you elaborate more on this, bcz it is not working till now.

Comment: Hi Rumen, thank you for your help, i have modified the code  and is working fine but i IE11 it is not working, i need help

Comment: did you try to add `event.which == 13` to become `if (event.which == 13 || event.keyCore == 13)`